# MVC Entity Framework Model not returning correct data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Run into a strange problem while writing an ASP.NET MVC site. I have a view in my SQL Server database that returns a few date ranges. The view works fine when running the query in SSMS.

When the view data is returned by the Entity Framework Model, It returns the correct number of rows but some of the rows are duplicated.

Here is an example of what I have done:

SQL Server code:

**EDITED: (table A)**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PhID] [int] NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ToDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [ID] ASC,
    [FromDate] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [PhID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ToDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [PhID] ASC )) ON [PRIMARY]
go

CREATE VIEW C as
SELECT  A.ID, 
        CASE WHEN A.PhID IS NULL THEN A.FromDate ELSE B.FromDate END AS FromDate, 
        CASE WHEN A.PhID IS NULL THEN A.ToDate ELSE B.ToDate END AS ToDate
FROM    A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.PhID = B.PhID
go

INSERT INTO B (PhID, FromDate, ToDate) VALUES (100, '20100615', '20100715')
INSERT INTO A (ID, PhID, FromDate, ToDate) VALUES (1, NULL, '20100101', '20100201')
INSERT INTO A (ID, PhID, FromDate, ToDate) VALUES (1, 100, '20100615', '20100715')

INSERT INTO B (PhID, FromDate, ToDate) VALUES (101, '20101201', '20101231')
INSERT INTO A (ID, PhID, FromDate, ToDate) VALUES (2, NULL, '20100801', '20100901')
INSERT INTO A (ID, PhID, FromDate, ToDate) VALUES (2, 101, '20101201', '20101231')
```

So now, if you select all from C, you get 4 separate date ranges

In the Entity Framework Model (which I call 'Core'), the view 'C' is added.

in MVC Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CoreEntities db = new CoreEntities();
        var clist = from c in db.C
                    select c;

        return View(clist.ToList());
    }

}
```

in MVC View:

```
@model List<RM.Models.C>

@{
    foreach (RM.Models.C c in Model)
    {
        @String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", c.FromDate)
        <span>-</span>
        @String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", c.ToDate)
        <br />
    }
}
```

When I run all this, it outputs this:

```
01-Jan-2010 - 01-Feb-2010
01-Jan-2010 - 01-Feb-2010
01-Aug-2010 - 01-Sep-2010
01-Aug-2010 - 01-Sep-2010
```

When it should do this (this is what the view returns):

```
01-Jan-2010 - 01-Feb-2010
15-Jun-2010 - 15-Jul-2010
01-Aug-2010 - 01-Sep-2010
01-Dec-2010 - 31-Dec-2010
```

Also, I've run the SQL profiler over it and according to that, the query being executed is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[FromDate] AS [FromDate], 
[Extent1].[ToDate] AS [ToDate]
FROM (SELECT 
      [C].[ID] AS [ID], 
      [C].[FromDate] AS [FromDate], 
      [C].[ToDate] AS [ToDate]
      FROM [dbo].[C] AS [C]) AS [Extent1]
```

Which returns the correct data

So it seems that the entity framework is doing something to the data in the meantime.

To me, everything looks fine! Have I missed something?

Cheers,
Ben

**EDIT:**

sorry, table A should be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PhID] [int] NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ToDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [ID] ASC,
    [FromDate] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: perhaps you should remove the MVC aspects of this question - as it's not really relevant. This appears to be a SQL/EF issue.

Comment: Thanks RPM, I just wanted to provide an easy way for people to test the situation. In any case, I've solved my own problem as outlined below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

The problem was with the way the view was mapped in the entity model.

When it was added, it made the entity key just the ID. I needed it over the ID and FromDate. So I included the FromDate in the entity key and it works fine.

Comment: I just had a very similar situation. My view worked just fine in SSMS, but my application brought back strange/duplicated results, but had the correct number of rows.  Checked my EF keys and some odd random assortment had been selected.  I selected the correct keys and it works fine now.  Very weird.